# Modify a key in a list of dictonaries based on some condition

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a use case where I need to modify the key name and value based on some condition. In JavaScript it's very simple using [`lodash lib`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15).

But in Python I don't find such a library.

input:

```
list_is = [{'access_level': 20, 'username': 'example1'}, 
           {'access_level': 50, 'username': 'example2'}]
```

output:

```
[{'is_admin': false, 'username': 'example1'}, 
 {'is_admin': true, 'username': 'example2'}]
```

Please note, here key `access_level` is changed to `is_admin` and the value changes if `access_level` = `50` then `true` or else `false`.

in a simple program, I can do something like this:

```
processed_list = []
for i in range(len(list_is)):
    processed_object = {}
    processed_object[username] = list_is[i]['username']
    processed_object[is_admin] = list_is[i]['access_level'] == 50 ? true : false
    processed_list.append(processed_object)
    
return processed_list
```

But since I am a beginner in Python, I am wondering if there are pythonic way of doing this (lambda operators, fnc or pydash).

Comment: Could you please clarify if you are searching for in-place modification? Title and text of your question are  a bit contradictory in this aspect.

Comment: You stated *I can do something like this* before the "program" that isn't in valid Python syntax. So you didn't even take that one step but asking for the "pythonic way"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you are mutating the dicts anyway, it makes little sense to create a new list. Simply use a loop, `dict.pop` and do it in-place:

```
for d in list_is:
    d["is_admin"] = d.pop("access_level") == 50
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `list_comprehension`:

```
>>> output = [dict(
               [('is_admin', v==50) if k=='access_level' else (k, v) 
                for k,v in elem.items()]
             ) 
             for elem in list_is]

>>> output
[{'is_admin': False, 'username': 'example1'},
 {'is_admin': True, 'username': 'example2'}]
```

Or,

```
>>> output = [{'is_admin': elem.pop('access_level')==50, **elem} for elem in list_is]
>>> output
[{'is_admin': False, 'username': 'example1'},
 {'is_admin': True, 'username': 'example2'}]
```

This will create a new list with desired dict formats, however, the original list's (`list_is`) contents will be changed, as `access level` keys would be popped. So as pointed out by @schwobaseggl, it is better to not create a separate list, so instead you can assign the list comprehension back to `list_is`.

Comment: If you are building new dicts anyway, there is little point in modifying the originals on top of that :) to an inbetween-state as well.

Comment: @schwobaseggl agreed.

Comment: @Wolf I did not because `"This will modify the original dicts"` is not factually incorrect, however as I can see, the word `modified` seems to be ambiguous, hence edited.

Answer (score 0):

This is your code with some modifications:

```
def make_smth(list_is):
    processed_list = []
    for i in range(len(list_is)):
        processed_object = {}
        processed_object["username"] = list_is[i]['username']
        processed_object["is_admin"] = list_is[i]['access_level'] == 50 
        processed_list.append(processed_object)

    return processed_list

make_smth(list_is)
```

or more pythonic way

```
processed_list = [{"is_admin": i["access_level"] == 50, 'username': i['username']}  for i in list_is]
```